# Front page and author in list of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx, front-matter

In my list of contents, the first row is the front page.

And in the second line, there is the name of the author

Is there a way to delete that from my list of contents?

Example: 
[image: The Table of Content with the first row and the second row which I want to delete]

And i have the following code in my prefix.

```
\toctitle{Ticketmanagement System-Mobil}
\titlerunning{Ticketmanagement System-Mobil}
\author{Alexander Mallinger}
\authorrunning{Ticketmanagement System-Mobil}
\tocauthor{Alexander Mallinger}
```

Comment: Chances of you getting a better answer improve, when you supplement your question with a minimum (non)working example that illustrates your problem.

Comment: i added a example ;)

Comment: It might help to see some actual code that generates your example.

Comment: In lyx, I only added the table of content

Comment: @user694501: Phew! This is not enough. You should add your full MWE so that we need not guess/type other details during troubleshooting. Now I can only guess: remove `\toctitle{Ticketmanagement System-Mobil}
` and `\tocauthor{Alexander Mallinger}` and it should help IMO.